# After installing SharePoint 2013 server Jan 2019 CU , build number is pointing to dec 2018 CU number

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, patching

We recently patched on SharePoint servers with Jan 2019 CU on SP 2013 Servers. After patching, the SharePoint build number is equivalent to Dec 2018 CU instead of Jan 2019 CU.

Is it anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a test in my SharePoint 2013, patched on SharePoint servers with Jan 2019 CU on SP 2013 Servers. After patching, the SharePoint build number is equivalent to Dec 2018 CU instead of Jan 2019 CU.

It is a normal behavior.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to make sure before any conclusion:

- make sure you ran config wizard on all SharePoint servers after patching.
- from add/remove program, Make sure Jan 2019 Kb patches listed there (kb4461605)
- also from `central admin > upgrade & migration > check product and patch installation status` on this page, make sure Jan 2019 KB number is listed as installed for all servers.
- lastly, run `get-spproduct -local`

if all above check pass then their is no fix in the Jan CU which change the configuration database schema. it is normal, [Read more here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2014/10/23/common-question-why-does-the-version-number-on-the-servers-in-farm-page-not-change-after-installing-october-cu/).